# Autowiring a bean in spring boot and it is null in the main java package but it works in the test package

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following two classes 
    AConfig.java 
    A_TestConfig.java
Now, when I autowire the bean "configuration" in the A_Test.java class it is not null. However, the bean "configuration" is null in the B.java class. The bean has been defined on a getter in the A.java class and as follows: `

```
public class A_TestConfig {
@Bean
    public Configuration configuration() {

        return new Configuration();
    }
}

public class AConfig {
   @Bean
public Configuration configuration()
 {
     }
```

`}`

```
public class B {
@Autowire 
Configuration configuration;   //this value is null
}
```

`public class BTest {
   @Autowire 
   Configuration configuration;  //not null here

   }`

Comment: Show where you're using `B` (e.g., calling its methods).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **@Configuration** to the classes which is having **@Bean methods**.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Component
```

Add @Component to the class header - this indicates that the class is a candidate to be scanned in order to autowire the define beans in your class